# Incorrectly accessing mapped array?

Tags: solidity

I have:

```
mapping (uint256 => uint64[]) public Arry;
```

I am trying to do:

```
Arry[123][0]++;
```

And I am getting the generic invalid opcode.

To me, I am accessing map key 123 which is a uint64 array. I am then incrementing the uint64 in position 0 by one. I don't understand why it dies here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Arry[123][0]` is out of bounds if `Arry[123]` has a length of `0`. Make sure the array has at least one element in it.

Your code works fine for me as long as I do `Arry[123].push(0)` somewhere first.

Comment: You're right. It worked after I deleted my build folder and ran truffle test.